# c# vb .net: base class for functions?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, function, lambda

I'm trying to do a function that takes a function as a parameter and returns a function which is a memoized version of the input.

Ok sry if that doesn't make sense but anyway, my question is is there a base class or interface for the function **DynamicInvoke** found in System.Func(of T) and System.Func(of T, T2) and System.Func(of T, T2, T3) etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DynamicInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) is a member of the [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) class.